# Performance improvements with threads

Tags: multithreading, performance

Can the performance of a CPU bound application be improved significantly thru use of threads on a multi-core processor? The number of lock conflicts are insignificant.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question, it depends on how well the application can be split into parallel chunks - see for example Amdahl's law, Gustafson's law.

Comment: The application is large like a gate level simulator with N identical threads where N is the number of cores.

Comment: Assume that the work can be evenly divided and there are no cases where threads are competing for resources.